# Turning a 3 way circuit into a 4 way

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an existing 3-way circuit that i'd like to add a 3rd switch to.  Current signal chain: Power -> Light -> 3 way switch (common red, traveler above common white, traveler red on the other side...blacks wire nutted together) -> Light -> 3 way switch (common black, traveler above common red, traveler white on the other side.

The addition i'm making is adding a 3 way switch where the power comes in and swapping out the middle 3 way switch with a 4 way.

I can't seem to find a diagram of a circuit like this that has lights between the switches.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't find it because it doesn't exist. It can be done, but only with an additional cable. Or smart switches.

Comment: Is replacing the existing cabling in the walls an option?

Comment: How does the second light work? There is no neutral going to it. Or do you have a /4 cable going there with a non-white used as neutral?